# Rounding a number to 10

Tags: c#, numbers, rounding

I am trying to round numbers to 10

ex:

6 becomes 10

4 becomes 0

11 becomes 10

14 becomes 10

17 becomes 20

How would I do this? 
Math.Round doesn't work with this as far as I know.

Comment: Why have you left out 5? Will it become 0 or 10?

Comment: And please be specific about 15, 25, -5 and -15 as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For `double` (`float` and `decimal` will require additional casting):

```
value = Math.Round(value / 10) * 10;
```

For `int` :

```
value = (int) (Math.Round(value / 10.0) * 10);
```

Comment: @Oded - you'd still have to cast back

Comment: Second note: by default `Math.Round` will perform a Banker's Round, which means 2.5 will round to 2, not to 3 (or in other words this example will round 25 to 20 instead of 30). You can force a "normal" round by overloading with a `MidpointRounding` enum param.